# How to dynamically change content depending on data from Facebook analytics?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, push-notification, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-analytics

Facebook have [deprecated](https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/484268408433790) their app notifications API so there is no way to push content to a users phone based on segments anymore, correct me if I'm wrong.

The problem is that I want to analyse Facebook analytic data programatically and display different products to my customers based on how they use the app, to do this I need access to Facebook analytics through a PHP SDK or JavaScript SDK. How do I access Facebook analytics programatically? I can't find anything in their PHP SDK which would let me do this.

Furthermore, I want to push notifications to specific segments of users, now that Facebook have deprecated their app notifications API, how can this be accomplished?

Could it be worth switching to Firebase / Google analytics, would these services allow me to accomplish these tasks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytics is primarily about post-event analysis, vs real-time optimization. All of the products you mention focus on post-event analysis and don't support you reading data out for a single individual (i.e. the current user), through an API or otherwise.

Comment: I see, so the solution would be to collect our own demographic data and build our own system for real-time optimisation.